# Swift generics issue: generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, generics, type-conversion, swift4

With this code:

```
public protocol LoginInfoBase: Decodable {
    var access_token: String? { get }
    var notifications: [PushNotification] { get }
}

public class ExampleLoginInfo: LoginInfoBase {
    public var access_token: String? = nil
    public var notifications: [PushNotification] = []
    
    public var user_info: UserInfo? = nil
    public var more_example_data: String? = nil
}

public func genericQuery<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, method: QueryType, params: Parameters?, decodable: T.Type,completionHandler: @escaping (Swift.Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
       <more code here>
    }
}

public func getLoginInfo(loginInfoClass: LoginInfoBase.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (Swift.Result<LoginInfoBase, Error>) -> Void) {
    genericQuery(urlString: "\(baseURL)/users/get_login_info/", method: .get, params: nil, decodable: loginInfoClass.self) { result in
        <more code here>
    }
}
```

I then call `getLoginInfo`...

```
getLoginInfo(loginInfoClass: ExampleLoginInfo.self) { result in 
    <more code here>
}
```

...and get this error:

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
Cannot convert value of type 'LoginInfoBase.Type' to expected argument type 'T.Type'
```

Here's the background. I'm trying to set up a generic login library that can be invoked with a class that contains user data that's specific to each app that it's used in. In this app I subclass `LoginInfoBase` as `ExampleLoginInfo` to add the extra user data. My intention is that library will then decode the user data returned from the server into ExampleLoginInfo.

Any ideas how to fix the error?

Comment: This is one of those “protocols don’t conform to themselves” issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/3141234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong signature:

```
public func getLoginInfo(loginInfoClass: LoginInfoBase.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (Swift.Result<LoginInfoBase, Error>) -> Void)
```

You mean this:

```
public func getLoginInfo<T: LoginInfoBase>(loginInfoClass: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (Swift.Result<LoginInfoBase, Error>) -> Void)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^
```

You need to pass a *concrete* type to `getLoginInfo` that conforms to LoginInfoBase. Not just any subtype. This matches your `genericQuery` method.

You should then modify your call to genericQuery as:

```
genericQuery(urlString: "\(baseURL)/users/get_login_info/",
             method: .get,
             params: nil,
             decodable: T.self) { ... } // use T.self here.
```

For more details, see [Alexander's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/3141234).